# In a Raw Queryset use ILIKE for case insensitive to check if one of the fields starts with a predifined letter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm using a raw Queryset and besides other things I check if a name start with a specific character.

I use `ILIKE`, to be case insesitive:

```
qs = self.raw(
     f'''SELECT t.id, t.name, 
     ................
     WHERE t.is_active = true AND t.name ILIKE \'%s%\' ORDER BY name ASC''',
                params=[char])
```

I get the following error:

```
tuple Index out of range
```

I presume it happens because of this: `ILIKE \'%s%\'`, the escaping is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add the `%` at the end of `char`:

```
qs = self.raw(
     '''SELECT t.id, t.name
     WHERE t.is_active = true AND t.name ILIKE %s ORDER BY name ASC''',
                params=[char + '%'])
```